# Rails - nilclass in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view I have -

```
<%= link_to 'remove pdf', controller: 'chap_comments', action: 'remove_file', id: comment.id %>
```

In my controller I have -

```
def remove_file
  @chap_comment.remove_chap_comment_pdf!
  @chap_comment.save
end
```

... I'm getting `undefined method`remove_chap_comment_pdf!' for nil:NilClass` - why is the class not recognised?

Similarly, the following -

```
<%= link_to 'remove pdf', remove_file_chap_comment_path(:id), method: :delete %>
```

...gets the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def remove_file
  @chap_comment = ChapComment.find(params[:id)
  @chap_comment.remove_chap_comment_pdf!
  @chap_comment.save
end
```

You've not found the chap comment or assigned it so @chap_comment is nil.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `id` in `link_to` but not using it to find the record thats why your are getting this error.use it :-

```
  @chap_comment = ChapComment.find(params[:id)
  ##do anything with this @chap_comment
```

see in the server log(console) ,you can see something like this:-

```
Processing by ChapsController#remove_file as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
```

**THAT MEANS -you are having the id but not using it though**